# MongoDB .Net Group or Aggregate query to get the records at or before (last) the given date

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Document so defined:

```ml
type FundAtDate = {
    Id: string
    Date: DateTime
    CurrencyCode: string
    Quantity: decimal
}
```

I'd like to make a query passing a date as paramerter to obtain the Quantity of ALL the currencies at the last date (the date equal or immediately before the reference date).

This is the test I need to pass:

```ml
open System
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit
open MongoDB.Driver

    [<Test>]
    member this.``GetFundsAtDate <should> return only expected records`` () =
        let atDate = DateTime(2000, 01, 31)
        let oldDate = atDate.AddDays(-20.);
        let beforeDate = atDate.AddDays(-10.);
        let afterDate = atDate.AddDays(+10.);
        // valid record
        let item_1= {Id=newGuid(); Date=toDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_1; Quantity=19m }
        let item_2= {Id=newGuid(); Date=beforeDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_2; Quantity=1m } 
        // non valid
        let item_3= {Id=newGuid(); Date=beforeDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_1; Quantity=1m }
        let item_4= {Id=newGuid(); Date=oldDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_1; Quantity=1m }
        let item_5= {Id=newGuid(); Date=afterDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_1; Quantity=1m } 
        let item_6= {Id=newGuid(); Date=oldDate; CurrencyCode=CURRENCY_2;  Quantity=1m } 
        addRecords([item_1; item_2; item_3; item_4; item_5; item_6])

        // execute
        let data = repository.GetFundsAtDate(toDate)

        data.Length |> should equal 2
        data |> should contain (equalWithin item_1)
        data |> should contain (equalWithin item_2)
```

Now, this is what I'd like to do using .Net Linq:

```ml
        member this.GetFundsToDate(date: System.DateTime): FundAtDate list = 
            // group by currency and get the latest
            let aggregate = base.Collection.Aggregate().Group((fun f -> f.CurrencyCode), fun g -> g.Where(fun g -> g.Date <= date).OrderBy(fun f -> f.Date).Last() )
            List.ofSeq( aggregate.ToEnumerable() )
```

but is not possible, as for other similar solutions, because these *System.Linq* opearions are not supported.

> System.NotSupportedException : The method OrderBy is not supported in the expression tree: {document}.Where(g => (g.Date <= 31/01/2000 00:00:00)).OrderBy(f => f.Date).

Searching online I only found solution where a BSonDocument is created and used but I've no idea how to solve this problem.

Apart from using the *BsonDocument* I'm also curious to understand if another solution with "pure .Net" syntax is possible.

Comment: `but I've no idea how to solve this problem.` - you can create any MQL command as BsonDocument and pass it into any Aggregate or Group in this case (there is implicit convertion between filters/pipeline/definition and BsonDocument). As for the typed LINQ issue, this looks like too complicated LINQ query. OrderBy is not supported inside Where inside Group, I assume the same story will be with Last. You can try to rewrite it with different operators, but I'm not sure that you will find supported LINQ query for your goal

Comment: however you cal look at this beta release http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver/crud/linq3/ that provides a new more effective LINQ implementation, but it's still only beta